# Convexity of piecewise linear function?

Tags: functions

I am questioning the convexity of the function below
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 5 &, 3 \leq x \leq 4 \\
                     1 &, 4 < x < 6 \\
                     5 &, 6 \leq x \leq 8 \end{cases}$$

Which has a corresponding graph like this:
[image]

Is this function Piecewise Linear Convex? According to wikipedia's definition it seems that it is not, but all of its parts are linear, convex. However, the combination of all pieces is not convex? Or is it?

Does this change if $f(x)$ is only defined over $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: The function is not convex, because its epigraph isn't. I don't know what "Piecewise Linear Convex" means.

Comment: No, it is not convex. For example the line segment connecting points $(2.5, f(2.5))$ and $(5, f(5))$ does not lie above the graph of $f$.

Comment: Discussing convexity of functions defined on $\mathbb{Z}$ does not make sense. For a function to be convex you first want its domain to be convex.

Comment: Any convex function on an interval is continuous in the interior.